# How to get the Jacobians matrix of outputs with respect to trainable parameters of a neural network in the training process?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, parameters, neural-network

I am using tensorflow 2.1.0 and Keras. I use stochastic gradient descent (SGD) to train my neural network (NN) model. I want to get the **Jacobian matrix** of the **outputs** with respect to **trainable parameters** of NN, (weights and bias), over each sample in the training process. How can I do it?

For example, I have **2 outputs**, 4 inputs, 2 hidden layers, 1 output layer. Both hidden layers have 3 neurons and output layer has 2 neurons. The Jacobian matrix a **2-by-35 matrix** (2 outputs and 35 trainable parameters).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jacobians can be calculated for Scalars as shown below:

```
x = tf.linspace(-10.0, 10.0, 200+1)
delta = tf.Variable(0.0)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  y = tf.nn.sigmoid(x+delta)

dy_dx = tape.jacobian(y, delta)
```

Please refer this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff#jacobians) for more information.

Comment: I need to calculate Jacobian of the outputs with respect to parameters in the training process and testing process. Does your method work?